# included jsp page can't call servlet

Tags: jsp, servlet-3.0, jspinclude, url-pattern

I have two jsp files login.jsp which has a login form

```
<form method ="post" action="LoginServlet">
..........
</form>
```

The second file is pages/errors.jsp which include login.jsp

```
<jsp:include file="../login.jsp" />
```

When login.jsp runs it calls LovinServlet correctly but when errors.jsp runs, the included login.jsp can't call LoginServlet.

How to solve? Thanks

Comment: login.jsp does not call LovinServlet. It prints a form so that the user can submit the form to LovinServlet by clicking a submit button. But it probably has to do with the .., meaning your login.jsp and errors.jsp are in different folders, right? And so the path of the servlet is different relative to them.

Comment: thank @developerwjk ,I change it to relative path and its work